# Unable to insert dynamic paragraph inside dynamic div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a code where there is a `div` created dynamically, and I'm adding this `div` to existing `div`. Then I'm creating a `p` element and want to add this to the dynamically created `div`.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="destribution-details" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" id="modal-lg">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var modal_lg = document.getElementById("modal-lg");
//modal header
var modal_content = document.createElement("div");
modal_content.className = "modal-content";
modal_lg.appendChild(modal_content);

var modal_header = document.createElement("div");
modal_header.className = "modal_header";
modal_content.appendChild(modal_header);


var closeButton = document.createElement("button");
closeButton.className = "close";
closeButton.setAttribute("data-dismiss", "modal");

var modal_title = document.createElement("h4");
modal_title.className = "modal-title";
modal_title.innerHTML = "Details 1";

modal_header.appendChild(closeButton);
modal_header.appendChild(modal_title);

//modal body
var modal_body = document.createElement("div");
modal_body.className = "modal-body";
modal_content.appendChild(modal_body);

var para = document.createAttribute("p");
modal_body.appendChild(para);

//modal footer
var modal_footer = document.createElement("div");
modal_footer.className = "modal-footer";
modal_lg.appendChild(modal_footer);


var closeButton = document.createElement("button");
closeButton.className = "btn btn-default";
closeButton.setAttribute("data-dismiss", "modal");
closeButton.innerHTML = "Close";
modal_footer.appendChild(closeButton);
```

When I run this, in my console I get an error saying `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type 'p' may not be inserted inside nodes of type 'DIV'.`

Please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/57yf14o4/

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> when I run this, in my console I get an error saying Uncaught
>   DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type
>   'p' may not be inserted inside nodes of type 'DIV'

`p` is also an element, so correct it as

```
var para = document.createElement("p");
```

Check the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57yf14o4/1/)

Comment: Or in short: replace `document.createAttribute("p");` by `document.createElement("p");`

Comment: @reporter yes, that is what I meant when I said *correct it as*. Thanks though.